# Explicit isomorphism between ${\rm SL}(2,{\Bbb R})$ and ${\rm SU}(1,1)$

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups, linear-groups

I have heard that there exists an isomorphism of real algebraic groups as in the title. I am asking for an *explicit isomorphism*.

**Motivation:** I need such an isomorphism for a calculation of Galois cocycles (with values in some other group).

Comment: They are conjugate within ${\rm SL}_2\Bbb C$ via the Cayley transform (which as a Moebius transformation swaps the real projective line and unit circle).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The elements of $SU(1,1)$ are the matrices of the form$$\begin{bmatrix}\alpha+\beta i&\gamma+\delta i\\\gamma-\delta i&\alpha-\beta i\end{bmatrix}$$with $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta\in\Bbb R$ such that $\alpha^2+\beta^2-\gamma^2-\delta^2=1$. Map each such matrix into$$\begin{bmatrix}\alpha-\delta&-\beta+\gamma\\\beta+\gamma&\alpha+\delta\end{bmatrix}\in SL(2,\Bbb R).$$That will give you your isomorphism.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you, José! This solves my problem. However, how can one find this answer, if one did not know it in advance?

Comment: I don't know any easy way of deducting this. It can be done by finding an isomorphism $\Psi$ between the Lie algebras $\mathfrak{su}(1,1)$ and $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\Bbb R)$ and using it to define a Lie group isomorphism. And you can find $\Psi$ by finding $3$ elements $H,X,Y\in\mathfrak{su}(1,1)$ such that $[H,X]=2X$, $[H,Y]=-2Y$, and $[X,Y]=H$.

Comment: Yes, an ${\frak sl}_2$-triple $(H,X,Y)$ in ${\frak su}(1,1)$. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Chances are, you used to know this (long time ago) when you took a complex analysis class.

You likely knew that every conformal automorphism of the unit disk in the complex plane has the form
$$
f(z)= \frac{az+b}{\bar{b}z+ \bar{a}}. 
$$
If you stare at this formula, you realize that this is just the group $PU(1,1)$. You can also see this by observing that the group $U(1,1)$ preserves the real quadric
$$
\{(z,w): z\bar z - w \bar w=0\} 
$$
Passing to the projectivization, we set $w=1$ and, hence, obtain the equation $z\bar z=1$. Thus, $PU(1,1)$ preserves the unit circle in the complex plane.

You also probably knew that the upper half-plane is conformal to the unit disk and that the group of conformal automorphisms of the former is $PSL(2, {\mathbb R})$, linear-fractional transformations with real coefficients.

Now, it remains to realize that $SU(1,1)$ is a nontrivial 2-fold covering space of $PU(1,1)$, ditto $SL(2, {\mathbb R})$ for $PSL(2, {\mathbb R})$.