# An isomorphism between $\mathrm{Spin}(2,1)$ and $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I was looking at the note in this post: https://mathoverflow.net/a/119716/38714,
and happened to see on Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_group#Indefinite_signature) that $\mathrm{Spin}(2,1)=\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$, but I could not think of or find a proof of this fact.

Is this "=" in the sense of Lie groups? Or is this local?

I think I see $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ inside the Clifford algebra of dimension $8$ by computing the bracket, but if I exponentiate the pure quaternions as in the note, they are, of course, something like $\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$. Then the group looks compact, which makes some sense since I guess they are similar to rotations. This also makes me confused...

Comment: Ok, I found this: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3955354/66607 being an inspiration. $a+bi+cj+dk\mapsto\begin{pmatrix} a+d & -b+c \\ b+c & a-d \end{pmatrix}$ where $a^2+b^2-c^2-d^2=1$, i.e., the unit quaternions, might be an isomorphism. I guess I also need to take a more careful look at the construction. It's a bit late for me, so I will think about it tomorrow morning.

Comment: Both are simply connected as algebraic groups, so these are indeed (globally) isomorphic as Lie groups (in any case the sign $=$ is abusive). The simplest way to see the isomorphism is maybe to check that both groups are connected Lie groups, have center of order two and are locally isomorphic to $SL_2(\mathbf{R})$.

Comment: You could start by showing an isomorphism of Lie algebras $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb R) \simeq \mathfrak{so}(2,1)$ -- I bet the adjoint representation of $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb R)$ is invariant w.r.t. a form of signature $(2,1)$, for which I see an obvious candidate. Then you can exponentiate. (I guess a lifted version, the adjoint rep of the group $SL_2(\mathbb R)$ on its Lie algebra, also leaving the Killing form invariant, just gives $PSL_2(\mathbb R) \simeq SO^+(2,1)$; it might be easy to lift that to the groups with centre, or not.)